# reorder automatically bootstrap elements after hidng some of them

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Let's suppose i have a bunch of bootstrap card elements (all have the same structure, only the titles differ). Let's suppose also that i have a user text input feild in the very top like this (Where the user will input his keywords) :

```html
<!-----------------SOME BOOTSTRAP DEPENDENCIES FOR U TO BE ABLE TO TEST THE CODE HERE-------->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--   Here is the content sorry if it's in french evry function will be fine with this --->
<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-start">
      <div class="col-12 my-3">
       <input type="text" name="search" id="searchFeild" class="w-100  border rounded border-secondary">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="cartes" class="row ">
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la première carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la deuxième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la troisième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la quatrième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la cinquième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la sixième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la septième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
       <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">titre de la huitième carte </h2>
         <p class="card-text">Le contenu de la carte en question sous forme d'un bref paragraphe</p>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Action sur la carte</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Now! How the hell to do ( I tried evry single thing) to get evrything reorganize itself proprely in my page after some of them are hidden ( By the filter search) ????????? Please help me if anybody can a little bit take a look at this.

Comment: Did you used `display:none` and `display:block` for hidden process?

Comment: I have suposed that the toggle function takes care of the display: none/block properties ! No?

Answer (score 0):

I used the JQuery toggle function like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#searchBar").on("keyup", function() {

          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          console.log("value: " + value + "has been entered.");
          console.log($('.card').filter(function(index) {
           $(this).toggle();
           if ($(this).find('.card-title').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {

            $(this).toggle(); 
           };
           
          }));
          
       });
    });
```